# Repository is not signed in docker build

Tags: docker, ubuntu, apt

I have the following Dockerfile that uses the latest Ubuntu image pulled from dockerhub:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest  
RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install -y  g++ llvm lcov
```

when I launch the docker build command, the following errors occur:

```
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
At least one invalid signature was encountered.

Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.

Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.

Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.

Reading package lists...

W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.

W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' is not signed.

W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is not signed.

W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' is not signed.
```

I read here https://superuser.com/questions/1331936/how-can-i-get-past-a-repository-is-not-signed-message-when-attempting-to-upgr that you can pass this error using --allow-unauthenitcated or --allow-insecure-repositories but both seem to me workarounds that may compromize security of the container.

**EDIT**

Tried to pull ubuntu:18.04, ubuntu:19:04, ubuntu:19.10 same error with different distro name

Comment: Are you working behind a proxy?

Comment: @7_R3X No, not at all

Comment: Other than `latest` did you try `ubuntu:18.04`?

Comment: yes, I tried 19.04, 19.10

Comment: I tried to pull a newer image and it worked for me. Looks like some bug in the image

Comment: I am encountering this error on Mac but increasing disk space, `docker image prune -a`, etc., do not work. Interestingly, `apt-get update` works if I run `docker run -it --privileged ubuntu:24.04` but fails without `--privileged`.

Comment: Manually updating Docker Desktop for Mac to the latest version fixed it for me.

Answer (score 394, accepted):

Apparently my root partition was full (maybe I've tried too many times to download packages through apt), and running `sudo apt clean` solved the issue

---

In addition, the following commands should help clean up space:

```
docker system df # which can show disk usage and size of 'Build Cache'
docker image prune # add -f or --force to not prompt for confirmation
docker container prune # add -f or --force to not prompt for confirmation
```

Comment: Using `docker image prune` and `docker container prune` resolved this for me.

Comment: `docker image prune` saved 52GB on my disk and made my build run again, thank you Antonio and Erik!

Comment: can someone explain why this failure can happen? This challenges my understanding of docker: there seem to be state kept in between run that don't make the runs deterministic.

Comment: @David天宇Wong I believe it's a disk space issue, rather than old build/run state being reused

Comment: I tried all of the above but my issue resolved after nuking the docker build cache. At first I looked at my docker usage by: `docker system df`. This told me that my build cache is 50+GB. Then I nuked it using `docker builder prune`.

Comment: Amazing... it was the solution, I was staring at everything but didn't realize my root partition had run out of space.

Comment: I had the same issue.  I am running Docker Toolbox on VirtualBox on top of Windows 10 and the `/var` mount filled up:
`E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/`

Comment: I came across this in a `docker buildx` build; `docker buildx prune` sorted things...

Comment: For me, `docker image prune` was not helping and I discovered I had to use `docker image prune -a`. I reclaimed about 50GB and fixed my build!

Comment: @Raashid following this advice, I ran `docker system df` and realized I needed to run `docker volume prune` to resolve the issue.

Comment: Doing ```docker system prune``` wasn't enough for me. I needed to delete images and run ```docker volume prune``` as well.

Comment: Running 'docker system prune' only reclaimed a couple of gigabytes (out of a couple of hundred), but seems to have solved the problem nevertheless.  I have no idea why, no disks were anywhere close to full, AFICT.  But thanks anyway, upvoted.

Comment: Using docker image prune and docker container prune resolved this for me as well.

Comment: Geez docker, can you give a better error message pls. Spend 1hr just to realise this is the root cause.

Comment: `docker buildx prune --all --force` freed up a lot of space for me

Comment: `At least one invalid signature was encountered.` is the very strange error message for the insufficient space issue! Surprisingly it resolves my problem.

Answer (score 141):

## Since Docker API v1.25+ ( released: Nov 18, 2019 )

Running the command below fixed the problem for me:

```
docker system prune --force
```

The `--force` flag stands for noninteractive prune.

Additionally, you may want to give a try to the prune volume commands:

```
docker volume prune --force
```

Comment: ```docker system prune``` wasn't enough for me. I also needed to delete images and run ```docker volume prune``` to resolve the issue.

Comment: thanks @JonasEicher, I've included your case into the answer

Comment: These can be combined into one: `docker system prune --all --force --volumes`

Comment: Thanks for sharing @AndriyIvaneyko! It worked running `docker system prune --force`

Comment: @xserrat Absolutely, happy it was useful for you !

Answer (score 62):

fixed by

```
docker image prune -f
```

looks like docker has a limit on maximum apt cache size on the host system

Comment: I needed to run docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q) as well.

Answer (score 45):

If you're using Docker Desktop, take care of the maximum disk image size you've specified in the settings. It can cause the issue if it gets full during the build ([source](https://evryn.dev/repository-is-not-signed-when-building-docker-image/)).

[image]

Comment: Thank you--- both this (increasing disk image size resource) and pruning my system resolved this for me on Docker/Mac.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. Weird that apt-get is not clearer about the issue.

Comment: Increasing disk image size helped me, thanks :)

Answer (score 31):

For Raspbian, upgrade `libseccomp` manually on the host system by using:

```
curl http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libs/libseccomp/libseccomp2_2.5.1-1_armhf.deb --output libseccomp2_2.5.1-1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libseccomp2_2.5.1-1_armhf.deb
```

This resolved my issue.

Original post is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263284/apt-update-throws-signature-error-in-ubuntu-20-04-container-on-arm).

Comment: Yes, that was it! It seems to be only true for the armhf-Raspberry OS. Everything works on my 64bit servers.

Comment: Solved for me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

As @Danila and @Andriy pointed out this issue can easily be fixed running:

```
docker image prune -f
docker container prune -f
```

but posting this answer, as running just one of them didn't work for me (on **MacOS X**) - running both however does.

Answer (score 9):

This helps me:

```
 docker volume prune
```

Answer (score 4):

I had to run container with `--security-opt seccomp:unconfined`.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem on one of my two machines. Doing a `ls -ld /tmp` I got

```
drwxrwxrwt 3 root root 4096 May 15 20:46 /tmp
```

for the working one and

```
drwxr-xr-t 1 root root 4096 May 26 05:44 /tmp
```

for the failing one. After I did `chmod 1777 /tmp`, it worked!!

EDIT:

So, I dived a little deeper into this problem and realized there was something fundamentally wrong. I put my problems in another question and later found the answer that solved this myself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62088961/7387935

The key point here is that on the machine that was working correctly I had aufs as storage driver and on the faulty one it was overlay2. After I changed that, all permissions were correct.

Comment: this one worked for me. I had moved the tmp folder to another drive and placed a simlink in root folder. That started to create problems with signature and many other errors. I did as you explained here, but then I moved the tmp folder back to root directory and deleted the simlink. I might just leave the tmp folder where it should stay.

Answer (score 2):

I tried again later and it worked.

From https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/898#issuecomment-539234070:

> That usually means the mirror is having issues (possibly partially out
> of date; i.e. not completely synced from other mirrors) and often
> clears itself up.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers all talk about creating more space for Docker by removing existing Docker items via `docker container prune`, `docker image prune` and `docker volume prune`. Alternatively it is also possible to increase the disk limit that Docker has set for it self (provided that you have enough disk space).

In Docker Desktop go to *Settings* > *Resources* and increase the "*Virtual disk limit*".

This has helped me since I work with several large docker images and don't want to bothered every time to prune.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me
`docker system prune -af --volumes`
and these other ones as well

```
docker image prune 
docker container prune
docker builder prune
docker volume prune
```

This running  `docker system df` and see if you need free space on one of your volumes

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by stopping all of my running containers (2, in my case).

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: try to uninstall ubuntu 22.04 from wsl and install Docker Desktop v4.23.0.**

I now have two machines with this error on one of them. I've tried all of your suggestions with no luck. At some point I've noticed the only difference between software versions is version of ubuntu installed on wsl as default distro. So I uninstalled 22.04, installed 20.04 for clear test case and guess what? It works!

*What a lovely day*

Answer (score -2):

I added `--network=host` to the build command.

```
docker build --network=host -t REPOSITORY:TAG  ./
```

Answer (score -2):

I had similar issue as you, and I have solved by installing a newer Docker version.

See error message below:

```
The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY XXXX NO_PUBKEY YYYY
```

My work-around was to uninstall Docker, and install the newest version.

###### Uninstalling Docker in RHEL 7.9 (as in CentOS):

- Stopping docker daemon:
  `sudo service docker stop`
- Uninstalling docker:

```
    sudo yum remove docker \
                      docker-client \
                      docker-client-latest \
                      docker-common \
                      docker-latest \
                      docker-latest-logrotate \
                      docker-logrotate \
                      docker-engine
```

- Remove Docker Directory Root:
  `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/`

##### Installing Docker

You can follow the official tutorial [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/).

If your VM does not have access to the internet, I personally found [this article](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/fci/6.5.0?topic=steps-upgrading-docker#d37886e117) useful.