# Using the same Docker image file permissions differ from machine to machine

Tags: docker, containers, file-permissions

I have a problem, that I cannot grasp at all. I'm running my Jenkins pipeline in a Docker container on the master node. Now I added another node and want to run the pipeline there as well.

However, using the same image I get different file permissions in the container:

```
### master
> docker image ls node:10.20.1-stretch
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
node                10.20.1-stretch     c5f1efe092a0        13 days ago         912MB
> docker run --rm -ti -u 1000:1000 node:10.20.1-stretch ls -la /home/node
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000 4096 May 15 20:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 3    0    0 4096 May 15 20:31 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  220 May 15  2017 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 3526 May 15  2017 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  675 May 15  2017 .profile

### node 1
> docker image ls node:10.20.1-stretch
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
node                10.20.1-stretch     c5f1efe092a0        13 days ago         912MB
> docker run --rm -ti -u 1000:1000 node:10.20.1-stretch ls -la /home/node
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 0 0 4096 May 26 05:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 0 0 4096 May 26 05:42 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 0  220 May 26 05:42 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 0 3526 May 26 05:42 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 0  675 May 26 05:42 .profile
```

I observed a similar behavior for the `/tmp` directory, which has `chmod 1777` on master and `1755` on node 1.

```
# master
> docker -v 
Docker version 19.03.9, build 9d988398e7
> dockerd -v 
Docker version 19.03.9, build 9d988398e7

# node 1
> docker -v
Docker version 19.03.10, build 9424aeaee9
> dockerd -v
Docker version 19.03.10, build 9424aeaee9
```

I assume the wrong behavior is on `node 1`, as the `/home/node` directory and all of its children are owned by `root:root` there, but the same directory is owned by `node:node` on the master. However, I already upgraded the Docker version on node 1 from 19.03.8 to 19.03.10 and nothing changed.

It there anything I don't understand about Docker containers? I have been working with them for a while, but never observed such a behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have change the storage driver from `overlay2` to `aufs`. Now I have the correct permissions.