# Unable to run apt-get update from docker container in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, apt-get

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 from the  Microsoft Store and installed docker on Ubuntu following the instructions [here](https://medium.com/faun/docker-running-seamlessly-in-windows-subsystem-linux-6ef8412377aa). I was able to get docker running but when I tried to build my docker image, it fails at the `RUN apt-get update` step. Similarly, when I run an Ubuntu container with `docker run -it ubuntu bash`, running `apt-get update` gives the following

> ```
> root@266ddcbcf737:/# apt-get update
> Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
> Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
> Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [111 kB]
> Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
>   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
> Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]
> Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
>   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
> Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
>   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
> Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
>   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
> Reading package lists... Done
> W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
> E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' is not signed.
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
> W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
> E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
> W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
> E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' is not signed.
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
> W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
> E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease' is not signed.
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
> ```

I have tried clearing apt-cache and regenerating it, running `apt-get clean` pruning docker system, and using  `--allow-unauthenticated` but nothing works. I ran df from docker container and ubuntu to check space remaining and I have mroe than 20GB remaining which should be sufficient right? What could be the issue?

> ```
> root@653e5734fa23:/# df
> Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
> overlay        215196196 192359380  22836816  90% /
> tmpfs          215196196 192359380  22836816  90% /dev
> tmpfs          215196196 192359380  22836816  90% /sys/fs/cgroup
> rootfs         215196196 192359380  22836816  90% /etc/hosts
> shm            215196196 192359380  22836816  90% /dev/shm
> root@653e5734fa23:/# exit
> exit
> me@DESKTOP:~$ df
> Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
> rootfs         215196196 192358800  22837396  90% /
> none           215196196 192358800  22837396  90% /dev
> none           215196196 192358800  22837396  90% /run
> none           215196196 192358800  22837396  90% /run/lock
> none           215196196 192358800  22837396  90% /run/shm
> none           215196196 192358800  22837396  90% /run/user
> cgroup         215196196 192358800  22837396  90% /sys/fs/cgroup
> C:\            215196196 192358800  22837396  90% /mnt/c
> ```

Docker information:

> ```
> me@DESKTOP~$ docker info
> Containers: 1
>  Running: 0
>  Paused: 0
>  Stopped: 1
> Images: 3
> Server Version: 17.09.0-ce
> Storage Driver: overlay2
>  Backing Filesystem: <unknown>
>  Supports d_type: true
>  Native Overlay Diff: true
> Logging Driver: json-file
> Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
> Plugins:
>  Volume: local
>  Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
>  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
> Swarm: inactive
> Runtimes: runc
> Default Runtime: runc
> Init Binary: docker-init
> containerd version: 06b9cb35161009dcb7123345749fef02f7cea8e0
> runc version: 3f2f8b84a77f73d38244dd690525642a72156c64
> init version: 949e6fa
> Kernel Version: 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft
> Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
> OSType: linux
> Architecture: x86_64
> CPUs: 4
> Total Memory: 15.84GiB
> Name: DESKTOP-DOC78SA
> ID: CHGU:3AXK:5MJK:XK3H:LXBS:BQJI:AGW6:SF7J:7FG3:BUBD:J55H:VXUM
> Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
> Debug Mode (client): false
> Debug Mode (server): false
> Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
> Experimental: false
> Insecure Registries:
>  127.0.0.0/8
> Live Restore Enabled: false
>
> WARNING: No memory limit support
> WARNING: No swap limit support
> WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
> WARNING: No oom kill disable support
> WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
> WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
> WARNING: No cpu shares support
> WARNING: No cpuset support
> ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repository is not signed in docker build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59139453/repository-is-not-signed-in-docker-build)

Comment: You can try removing stopped containers and dangling image with `docker container prune` and `docker image prune`. This will help if the problem is related to a lack of storage.

Comment: I have tried and it doesn't work for me. Also ran df and found that I have more than 20GB remaining.